# How can I add a circle behind the content of an element?

Tags: html, css

I have a web page. In this page, I have several font icons that I'm using. I would like to put a gray circle behind these icons. Effectively, I want to create a gray circle behind some content. At this time, I'm trying, I have the following:

```css
.circled {
  background-color: gray;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1.0rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="circled">
  <i class="my-icon"></i>
</div>
```

While the content is "circled", the circle tends to be more of an oval. I would like to always render a perfect circle. Is there a way to do this with CSS? If so, how?

Comment: If you want a circle the item has to be **square**. Start there.

Comment: Alternatively, use a radial gradient

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: flex` and align and justify the content to the center.

```css
.circled{
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
  background-color: grey;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  justify-content: center;
 }
```

```html
<div class="circled">
 <i class="my-icon">Icon</i>
</div>
```

Comment: Please correctly read what the author of this questions wants. He does not want to have a lot of text inside the circle, instead he wants to place an icon.

Comment: The challenge is, my content is variable size. For that reason, I can't set the `height` and `width` properties on the parent element via the `circle` class. I'm trying to figure out a way to do it more dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I've provided two snippets of code to demonstrate that this should work with various amounts of squares.

I did this by making a square `square_holder` to hold each square. Tweaking may have to be done to either `square_holder` or `square` based on how you would like the rows to display. Personally I like rows of three.

Try the following examples:

1. One Square

```css
.circled {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: grey;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  justify-content: center;
}

.square_holder {
  height: 60%;
  width: 60%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.square {
  height: 30%;
  width: 30%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #555;
}
```

```html
<div class="circled">
  <div class="square_holder">
    <i class="square">
    </i>
  </div>
</div>
```

2. Nine Squares

```css
.circled {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: grey;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  justify-content: center;
}

.square_holder {
  height: 70%;
  width: 70%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.square {
  height: 30%;
  width: 30%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #555;
}
```

```html
<div class="circled">
  <div class="square_holder">
    <i class="square">
    </i>
    <i class="square">
    </i>
    <i class="square">
    </i>
    <i class="square">
    </i>
    <i class="square">
    </i>
    <i class="square">
    </i>
    <i class="square">
    </i>
    <i class="square">
    </i>
    <i class="square">
    </i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: The challenge is, my content is variable size. For that reason, I can't set the `height` and `width` properties on the parent element via the `circle` class. I'm trying to figure out a way to do it more dynamically.

Comment: @Dev Updated answer. Let me know if it helps at all

Answer (score 0):

```css
.my-icon::before {
 content: 'I';
}

.circle {
  background-color: gray;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 1.0rem;
}
```

```html
<span class="circle my-icon">
</span>
```

Comment: The challenge is, my content is variable size. For that reason, I can't set the `height` and `width` properties on the parent element via the `circle` class. I'm trying to figure out a way to do it more dynamically.

Comment: Is it a single character ?

Comment: I think you'll have to try with JS.